# footnotebackref leads footnote on heading to a wrong page

Tags: sectioning, hyperref, footnotes, footmisc

I am using XeLaTeX with these settings relating to my question:

```
\documentclass[a5paper, 11pt, openany]{ctexbook}
\usepackage[bottom, hang, stable]{footmisc}
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\textsf{\arabic{footnote}}}
\setlength{\footnotemargin}{0.5cm}
\setlength{\skip\footins}{0.25cm}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{footnotebackref}

\begin{document}

\chapter*{Title line 1\footnote{foot note here} \\ line 2}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Title appears in toc}
\markboth{leftmark}{}
\label{mark}
\input{"filename.tex"}

\end{document}
```

The references in body text seem working just fine. But this particular one in a `chapter*` title does not. In my actual document, click the footnote (e.g. 3) it will lead me to the body text linked to previous footnote (e.g. 2), but click the link at the body text works just fine too.

Comment: You're describing a problem that can't be reproduced by your example. There's no previous footnote and the `filename.tex` isn't available too.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I know that because I didn't alter too much from my original code. But it will be reproduced if one's have two pages with a footnote on regular text on page one and a footnote on heading on page two. Click it on page two it will go back to page one.